# I want to make it so that when the timer ends, when there are still 5 seconds left, an action occurs

Tags: java, android, android-studio, timer

How to make this action happen at the end of the time when there are still 5 seconds left.

This is the code of the action that I want to do when there are 5 seconds left from the timer:

```
mTextViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    zooming_second = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Level1.this, R.anim.watch_zoo);
    mTextViewCountDown.startAnimation(zooming_second);
    soundPlay(watch);
```

In this method:

```
//variable start
    private static final long START_TIME_IN_MILLIS = 60000;
    private TextView mTextViewCountDown;
    private CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    private boolean mTimerRunning;
    private long mTimeLeftInMillis = START_TIME_IN_MILLIS;
//variable end

private void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;

                int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
                int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

                String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
                mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);

                mTimerRunning = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                TimeOutDialog();
                soundPlay(time_out_sound);
                mediaPlayer1.stop();
                tadam_false.stop();
                tadam_true.stop();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    private void pauseTimer () {
        mCountDownTimer.cancel();
        mTimerRunning = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `onTick(long)` method simply check how many seconds are left. And if it is five, trigger your action.

**EDIT** 
My approach to hitting the right time would be something like this:

```java
if (Math.abs(mTimeLeftInMillis - 5000) < 100) {
    // start the animation
}
```

This would avoid issues with `if (mTimeLeftInMillis == 5000)` as it gives it some buffer. It's needed because it will not trigger at exactly 5000 milliseconds.

Comment: It doesn't work but something like this is needed:
`if (mTimeLeftInMillis = 5000){
                    //
}`

Comment: it's because it will never trigger on exactly 5000 milliseconds. It may be 4995 or 5012 or something. You can use <= to make sure your action triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I did it like this:

```
                 if (mTimeLeftInMillis <= 6000){
                   mTextViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                   zooming_second = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Level1.this, 
               R.anim.watch_zoo);
                   mTextViewCountDown.startAnimation(zooming_second);
                   soundPlay(watch);
               }
```

Comment: This will load animation every time it ticks and milliseconds left are below 6000. My approach would be something like this: `if(abs(mTimeLeftInMillis - 5000) < 100) { /* start animation */ }`.

Comment: @PrimožIvančič what is "abs"?

Comment: It returns absolute value. More here: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/abs.html. Java version of it is: `Math.abs(someNumber)`. I also added this to my answer.