# How i can make it without bug - Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I have a time counter bug in the game, how to fix it?
In my game, when there are 6 seconds left, the timer turns red and the animation is played, but sometimes the code freezes :(

It is this code that is bugging me, how to implement it differently:

```
if (mTimeLeftInMillis == 6000){
                    mTextViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    mTextViewCountDown.startAnimation(zooming_second);
                    soundPlay(watch);
                }
```

Here is the detailed code:

```
private void startTimer() {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(mTimeLeftInMillis, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                mTimeLeftInMillis = millisUntilFinished;

                if (mTimeLeftInMillis == 6000){
                    mTextViewCountDown.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    mTextViewCountDown.startAnimation(zooming_second);
                    soundPlay(watch);
                }

                int minutes = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) / 60;
                int seconds = (int) (mTimeLeftInMillis / 1000) % 60;

                String timeLeftFormatted = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds);
                mTextViewCountDown.setText(timeLeftFormatted);

                mTimerRunning = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                mTimerRunning = false;
                TimeOutDialog();
                soundPlay(time_out_sound);
                mediaPlayer1.stop();
                tadam_false.stop();
                tadam_true.stop();
                watch.stop();
                mTextViewCountDown.clearAnimation();
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Comment: This looks a lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71659936/i-want-to-make-it-so-that-when-the-timer-ends-when-there-are-still-5-seconds-le

Comment: Is it above all the code you wrote? Have you solved this or not yet?